# how to filter empty values in a column in powershell

Tags: powershell, null, multiple-columns, is-empty

i have input file text.csv

```
"#P","A","E","S"
"1","2","3","4"
"3","5","6",""
"A","B","C",""
"D","F","G","H"
```

I want output csv file export.csv as

```
"P","A","E","S"
"1","2","3","4"
"D","F","G","H"




 $File1 = Import-Csv -Path "test.csv" -Header "P","A","E","S" | Where { $_.S -ne $null } | Export-Csv "export.csv" -Force -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: An empty string is not the same as a null value, but you can use ```Where { -not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.S) }``` to test for either. And as an aside, it’s preferable to do ```$null -eq …``` instead of ```… -eq $null``` because you’ll get an unexpected “contains”-type comparison if the expression is enumerable - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/utility-modules/psscriptanalyzer/rules/possibleincorrectcomparisonwithnull?view=ps-modules for details…

Comment: You should *not* assign the pipeline to a variable (remove `$File1 =`). Just: `Import-Csv -Path "test.csv" -Header "P","A","E","S" | Where { $_.S -ne $null } | Export-Csv "export.csv" -Force -NoTypeInformation`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained earlier in the comments, *a [Comma-separated values (csv)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file typically stores tabular data (numbers and text) in plain text*, in which case each line will have the same number of fields.

Based on this you might assume that the [`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv) and [`ConvertFrom-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-csv) should never return a `$Null` for a property (column) value but just an empty string:

```
$Csv = @'
1,2,3,4
3,5,6,
A,B,C,
D,F,G,H
'@
$Csv |ConvertFrom-Csv -Header "P","A","E","S" |
    ForEach-Object { if ($Null -eq $_.S) { 'Null' } else { 'String' } }

String
String
String
String
```

But be careful with this assumption as this is not always the case. If not just the last value is omitted but also the preceding comma, the concerned `ConvertFrom-Csv` - and `Import-Csv` cmdlet might return a `$Null` (note that there is no comma behind the `A,B,C` in the following example):

```
$Csv = @'
1,2,3,4
3,5,6,
A,B,C
D,F,G,H
'@
$Csv |ConvertFrom-Csv -Header "P","A","E","S" |
    ForEach-Object { if ($Null -eq $_.S) { 'Null' } else { 'String' } }

String
String
Null
String
```

Besides that, there is an unfortunate bug in the concerned `ConvertFrom-Csv` - and `Import-Csv` cmdlet where [the last cell of an empty column read by ConvertFrom-Csv is inconsistently `$Null` `#17702`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/17702):

```
$Csv = @'
1,2,3,
3,5,6,
A,B,C,
D,F,G,
'@
$Csv |ConvertFrom-Csv -Header "P","A","E","S" |
    ForEach-Object { if ($Null -eq $_.S) { 'Null' } else { 'String' } }

String
String
String
Null
```

Therefore I would be better safe than sorry and test on both `$Null` (`$Null -ne $_.S`)<sup>**1)**</sup> *and* an empty string (`$_.S -ne ''`) which can be simplified to just: `... |Where-Object { $_.S } |...` this results in a so called "Truthy" condition if the concerned field is not empty (or `$Null`), see also [Conversion to Bool](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/lang-spec/chapter-06#62-conversion-to-bool)):

```
$Csv = @'     # Or as in your revised question:
1,2,3,4       # "1","2","3","4"
3,5,6,        # "3","5","6",""
A,B,C,        # "A","B","C",""
D,F,G,H       # "D","F","G","H"
'@
# Import-Csv -Path "test.csv" -Header "P","A","E","S" |
#     Where-Object { $_.S } |Export-Csv "export.csv" -Force -NoTypeInformation
$Csv |ConvertFrom-Csv -Header "P","A","E","S" |
    Where-Object { $_.S } |ConvertTo-Csv

"P","A","E","S"
"1","2","3","4"
"D","F","G","H"
```

> **1)** if you check for `$Null`; [`$Null` should be at the left side of the comparison operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-nul#checking-for-null)

Comment: it was working, Thank you so much.